# how to persist wkwebview permission.Notification between web push notifications - ios 16.4

Tags: ios, permissions, persistence, wkwebview, web-push

Apple just released a new feature with iOS 16.4: web push notifications !

I've been testing this feature and it works well. To make this feature works, I must add my website as an app on the user home screen.

My website push some content and when you click on the notifications, it open it.

The all process works well, but the webview embedded de-facto in the application keep open my modal to get the end user web push subscription notification object. My diagnostic is the following:

the webview (wkwebview) doesn't persist the `permission.Notification` value to `allow`, each time a user open the notification (and resets to `default`)

On "reals" browsers, the value is correctly persisted inside the browser settings.